# Where are perl constants replaced by their values?

Tags: perl, constants

I tried to `use constant` values in perl and stumbled upon the following weird behaviour:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

use constant {
    a => "b"
};

my $c = { a => a };
my %d;
$d{a} = a;

print Dumper($c);
print Dumper(\%d);
```

will output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 'b'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 'b'
        };
```

The constant `a` was replaced on the right hand side of the expressions `$d{a} = a` and `a => a`, but not on the left side.

I know that constants are implemented using inlinable subs ([documented here](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#TECHNICAL-NOTES)) and that sub names evaluate to their names if they aren't predeclared ([documented here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)), but I can see no reason why in my example `a` evaluates once to the value and once to the name in the same line of code, especially in the assignment to the hash - The `a => a` might be a consequence of `=>` interpreting the left site as a string if it begins with a letter.

Sidenote: Adding parantheses to make the sub-call explicit yields the expected result:

```
# ...
my $c = { a() => a }; # or my $c = { a, a };
my %d;
$d{a()} = a;
# ....
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => 'b'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => 'b'
        };
```

(all examples tested with perl 5.18)

Comment: Honestly, I tend to find the CONSTANT module just more trouble than it's worth, and tend to 'just' use upper case named package vars.

Comment: I use [Const::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/~leont/Const-Fast-0.014/lib/Const/Fast.pm) and haven't had problems. See [this review](http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html) for choices. Here is also a recent [article](https://www.nu42.com/2016/05/perl-define-constants.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The end of the [constant](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) page, at [CAVEATS](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#CAVEATS), has the answer

> You can get into trouble if you use constants in a context which automatically quotes barewords (as is true for any subroutine call). For example, you can't say `$hash{CONSTANT}` because `CONSTANT` will be interpreted as a string.

It then proceeds with the solution you found

> Use `$hash{CONSTANT()}` or `$hash{+CONSTANT}` to prevent the bareword quoting mechanism from kicking in.

Then it spells this out for hashes as well

> Similarly, since the `=>` operator quotes a bareword immediately to its left, you have to say `CONSTANT() => 'value'` (or simply use a comma in place of the big arrow) instead of `CONSTANT => 'value'`.

Comment: Congrats on reaching 10k.

Comment: Urg. They really shound have written this to the total top of the page. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, thank you :)  Going from scratch and learning how to do this has been ... an experience.

Comment: @urzeit  Yeah, it is _just_ past the part you quoted!  The upside may be that you must have learned way more by having to dig?