# What are the pitfalls in using bare words in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, quotes, bareword

I understand that bare words can be used as strings in quoting operators (q//, qq//), hash keys, etc. I'm personally not too thrilled about this because I can't get over the mental expectation that a literal string should be quoted, as in C, C++. However, if I were to adopt mixed uses of quoted strings and bare words, I want to make sure that I don't accidentally shoot myself in the foot where bare words would not behave correctly at runtime.

Please exclude use cases where 'use strict' would catch them as errors at compile time. I always enable 'strict' mode, so I'm not concerned about these cases.

Below is a code illustration based on the answers and comments provided:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use constant SIZE => "const_size";

sub size {
    return "getsize";
}

my $href = {
    size => 1,
    getsize => 2,
    const_size => "CONST_SIZE",
    SIZE => "LARGE",
};

print "constant SIZE:", SIZE, "\n";
print "1. \$href->{size}:", $href->{size}, "\n";
print "1a. \$href->{size()}:", $href->{size()}, "\n";
print "2. \$href->{getsize}:", $href->{getsize}, "\n";
print "3. \$href->{SIZE}:", $href->{SIZE}, "\n";
print "3a. \$href->{(SIZE)}:", $href->{(SIZE)}, "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ./bare_word.pl
constant SIZE:const_size
1. $href->{size}:1
1a. $href->{size()}:2
2. $href->{getsize}:2
3. $href->{SIZE}:LARGE
3a. $href->{(SIZE)}:CONST_SIZE
```

It appears that with respect to **hash keys**, bare words behave as expected in all cases. To override the behavior, we'd need to explicitly disambiguate.

Comment: If it's inside `q` or `qq`, it *is* quoted, so you can't call it a bareword. (`q` is exactly equivalent to single quotes, `qq` is exactly equivalent to double quotes).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I call it bare word in q// because of their appearance. And yes, I'm asking about runtime errors.

Comment: Another example came up in  [where-are-perl-constants-replaced-by-their-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094827/where-are-perl-constants-replaced-by-their-values/41094880#41094880).

Comment: So... ehm... in your mind, what does a *quoting* operator do, if not *quote* its content?

Comment: Your comment *"I call it bare word in `q//` because of their appearance"* worries me. Can you explain what you mean about their appearance, and how it's different from the appearance of `''` and `""`? I could begin to understand if you had said `qw//` but even that's something very different. I think you're misleading yourself somehow and I can't follow your train of thought.

Comment: *"Please exclude use cases where 'use strict' would catch them"* Why are you interested in code *without* `use strict`? You shouldn't be working with code like that unless you have legacy code that is too big to risk refactoring.

Comment: @Borodin, by appearance, I refer to the "textual appearance" on the screen, on paper, in front of our eyes. Perhaps, single and double quotes are the exception because I think it's obvious they are not bare words by their appearance. 

I asked to exclude cases detected by "use strict" because they can be caught at compile time. I'm only interested in problematic cases where none of the Perl facilities can help and thus go unnoticed and blow up in runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Please exclude use cases where 'use strict' would catch them as errors at compile time.*

`use strict;` entirely prevents the use of [barewords](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Barewords). Allowing barewords allows typos to fail very silently and/or subtly.

The documentation claims lowercase barewords could be misinterpreted as function calls in future versions of Perl, but that's not true. New functions would need to be enabled like `say`.

---

That said, I think you actually mean to talk about auto-quoted hash keys. There is a potential for confusion in that one might write `$hash{foo}` expecting it to be equivalent to `$hash{foo()}`. But not only is `foo` (as opposed to `foo()`) a weird way to call a sub in the first place, noone would want to write `$hash{foo()}` in the first place. (An argument would surely be required.)

The only thing preventing the chance of the code being misinterpreted from being infinitesimally small is the possibility of constants being used as hash keys. `$hash{CONSTANT}` would fail. One would need to use `$hash{(CONSTANT)}`, `$hash{+CONSTANT}`, or some other form of disambiguation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can shoot yourself in the foot by not quoting things properly:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e'
    my %h;
    $h{"foo-bar"} = 1;
    print Dumper \%h
'
$VAR1 = {
          'foo-bar' => 1
        };

$ perl -MData::Dumper -e'
    my %h;
    $h{foo-bar} = 1;
    print Dumper \%h
'
$VAR1 = {
          '0' => 1  # oops!
        };
```

However, strict mode turns this from an uncaught logic error into a syntax error:

```
$ perl -Mstrict -MData::Dumper -e'
    my %h; 
    $h{foo-bar} = 1; 
    print Dumper \%h
'
Bareword "foo" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Bareword "bar" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

...unless:

```
$ perl -Mstrict -MData::Dumper -e'
    sub foo { 1 }
    sub bar { 1 }

    my %h;
    $h{foo-bar} = 1;
    print Dumper \%h
'
Ambiguous use of -bar resolved as -&bar() at -e line 1.
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 1  # oops!
        };
```

Moral of the story? Always `use strict;`, and always quote hash keys that aren't [identifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Identifier-parsing) (identifiers contain letters, numbers, and underscores only, and the first character cannot be a number).

Comment: When I run the above code, I don't get the line of "Ambiguous use of -bar". 

The version of my Perl is: This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 2 (v5.22.2) built for cygwin-thread-multi.

And your example of (%h{foo-bar}) is a use case that I'm looking for. Are there other cases?

Comment: @Ltf4an The warning was spurious, so it was [removed in 5.22.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5220delta.html#Diagnostic-Removals). That's not the important part, though.

Comment: @Ltf4an Yes, there are similar pitfalls with the fat comma operator: `perl -Mstrict -MData::Dumper -e'sub foo { 1 } sub bar { 1 } my %h = (  foo.bar => 1 ); print Dumper \%h'`

Comment: Per your comment above, I've updated the description to use the term "pitfall." I think it's more descriptive of what I'm looking for.

Comment: When the last time you write `sub foo.bar { ... }`? The only real problem is `$hash{CONSTANT}`.